OP Am Voltage Regulator Reference Voltage
I have a fundamental design question. I am building a high-current linear DC power supply with an adjustable output voltage range of 10 to 15 volts. In my design, I selected a 5-volt precision Zener as the reference voltage because it made it easy to calculate feedback resistor values.
So here is my question: Is it better to use a lower voltage reference, like 2.5 volts, or something closer to the output voltage of lower DC gain?
My priorities are accuracy and stability. My gut tells me that a higher voltage is better for lowering the gain toward unity. So, should I use lower or higher gains?

Zeners generally are not known for high "accuracy and stability", unless you mean something like "VRE3050+5V, Low Noise Precision Voltage Reference".

I am using precision shunt voltage references like an LT1634 series.

In an adjustable voltage regulator, the reference voltage sets the minimum practical output voltage, so keep that in mind. With a 5 V reference, you can't regulate an output below 5 V without additional components (which can introduce more error).

Let's assume your circuit looks something like this (from the LT1634 datasheet), disregarding the reference voltage and the high current part of the circuit:


My priorities are accuracy and stability.

Are there specific requirements on this? The following are some factors that contribute to the these requirements:

Accuracy and stability of resistors
Accuracy and stability of the potentiometer
OpAmp power supply rejection ratio
Other non-ideal OpAmp characteristics variation with temperature


So, should I use lower or higher gains?

To summarize within the question scope (and with the information provided): you may have a 1.0 gain with 5% accuracy or a 10.0 gain with 0.01% accuracy.
If you share more details about the project we could be able do provide a more detailed analysis.

You are using a bandgap reference that internally amplifies a ~1.25V voltage reference to get 2.5 or 5V.
You are then going to use that to determine your output voltage.
I doubt there will be more than a nominal difference in stability between using a 2.5V reference of the same type and a 5V reference, and, in a well-designed circuit, and possibly differences could go either way. For example the noise of the 5V reference is more than double that of the 2.5V reference.
There would be more gain required with a 2.5V reference, but is that actually limiting… and would using a higher voltage shunt reference lead to worse line regulation… lots of factors come into play.
